# ASP.NET Button submits page and I can't stop it

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple proof of concept web page. It uses one master page and one content page, the default one, `default.aspx`. I'm doing some client side debugging with alert boxes. I dragged an asp.net button onto the page and set `CausesValidation = false` and `UseSubmitBehavior = false` and yet when I click it the page submits. 
What am I doing wrong?

Here is a design time code....

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  UseSubmitBehavior="False" CausesValidation="False" />
```

Here is Runtime render, wth is it putting in a PostBack?

```
<input type="button" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1" value="Button" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1" />
```

--Update--
Thanks Volkan Paksoy, that worked. For those who suggested HTML buttons, that worked too and that is what I used, but I was just curious why the ASP.NET button wouldn't work. It's something I should know and probably something I knew and forgot. Thanks for the help

Comment: show aspx markup for the button and generated html (from browser "view page source")

Comment: Could you change the type of input from `submit` to `button`?

Comment: Use a simple `Html` `<input type="button" ... />`. The `<asp:Button .../>` will cause a post back when clicked...

Comment: @Roto If Volkan Paksoy solved the problem, **please mark it as *Answer***.  ***FYI***: please do not edit your question just to say thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use asp:Button and disable submit you can add OnclientClick function such as:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
        CausesValidation="False" 
        OnClick="Button1_Click" 
        Text="Button" 
        UseSubmitBehavior="False"
        OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

This should stop the postback. But you can simply use an input too of course. This is just one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a button that does not submit the page/postback to the server, you could create one using raw HTML like so:

```
<input type="button" />
```